# what does "たすかれます" mean and use for？

Tags: meaning

I know 助かります (助かる)　means:　to be saved; to be rescued; to survive.

Imperative form : 助かれ

but people say  助かれます(i.e. Amazon.co.jp delivery man came earlier than specified time and i said 早いですね、he replied 助かれます, i did not understand)

N.B: I am learning Japanese (beginner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think might be hearing 「助か**り**ます」, which would be a way to say "thanks" when something you did was helpful.